# Implementation for JSONPARSE is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every time i add `compile com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1` to use JSONParse and others, my app won't build or run and it shows these errors:

```
AGPBI:
{
   "kind": "error",
   "text": "Program type already present: org.hamcrest.BaseDescription",
   "sources": [
      {

      }
    ],
    "tool": "D8"
}

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyPOS\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyPOS\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar
```

A bunch of those, but i edit it to be smaller.
I don't know if it's the implementation itself, but all i know is that when i comment it, the error goes away
But the thing is that i need it to use JSONParse and all that stuff.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, have you tried GSON ? :) It's much simpler to use. And that error, I think you will need Multidex, try to look it up! Best of luck :)

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your error, I suggest using Multidex, since you are over your 65k method limit.

To read more about it, try this link: http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Also, I would suggest using GSON library over that one since it's more widely used. (Personal preference too)